# the delete query cant getting the value from the form

Tags: asp-classic

i want to delete the booking record from the booking table but the delete query cant getting the value from the form

```
<form method="post" action="">
Enter booking Id<input type="text" id='bookid' name='bookid' required>
<button class="button1" id="bcancel" name="bcancel" value="cancel">Cancel 
Booking</button>
</form>
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")    
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"    
conn.Open(Server.Mappath("Aurangabad1.mdb"))
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

dim am,del
del="cancel"
am=request("bcancel")
if(am=del) then
sql="delete from booking where bid= '"& Request.form("bookid") & "'"
on error resume next
conn.Execute sql,info
if err<>0 then
Response.Write("<center>Booking Not Canceled..!</center>")
else
Response.Write("<center><h2>" & info & " Booking Canceled</h2></center>")
end if
end if
conn.close
%>
```

Comment: While debugging, get rid of the "on error resume next". also, do a response.write of all your querystring and form fields. What do you get?

Comment: i tried that also it write the value. but the query did not taking the value